# html in jade/pug page needs a custom request header tag

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I hope I ask this question well enough.  I'm not the strongest of jade/pug developers.

I've built a web page in jade.
The page has a from and uses post as the method and navigates to a different page.

I need this jade page to include a custom web request-header value when the browser sends the request to my node.js server.

**How do I get the custom header into the request of the jade html?**

This isn't about the header of a template of the page that will be rendered in the browser.  This is about the html request header.

BUT the page does `extends layout`.  So my page is wrapped in a layout jade template.

Thanks for considering your responses.

Comment: Doesn’t have anything to do with the template engine, just HTML, and HTML forms can’t do that.

Comment: @Ryan Can I do it in a $.ajax() post?  Using the $.ajax() post on the jade page?

Comment: Yes. See “headers” in https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.